# Django admin error ValidationError: ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with'] due to conditional inline use

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-tools

I have a custom `User` model(`AbstractUser`) and a `Stock` model. Assume there's multiple user roles `manager, supplier` etc. The manager can be able to view other **manager's details and supplier details**.

The `User` model got a **conditional inline** which shows the **stocks of each supplier if the user role is equalled to `supplier`**.(Here role is a `PositiveSmallIntegerField` with choices and `SUPPLIER = 2`)

```
class SupplierStockInline(admin.StackedInline):
    """ Inline to show stocks of a supplier """

    model = Stock
    extra = 0


@admin.register(User)
class UserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    """ User """

    fieldsets = [
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        ('Personal info', {'fields': (
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            ... some custom fields...
        )}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': (
            'is_active',
            'is_staff',
            'is_superuser',
            'role',
            'groups',
            'user_permissions',
        )}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')})
    ]

    list_display = [...]
    search_fields = [...]

    # --- the source of the problem ---

    inlines = []

    def get_inlines(self, request, obj):
        """ Show inlines, stocks of supplier """
        try:
            if obj.role == SUPPLIER:
                return [SupplierStockInline]
        except:
            pass
        return []
    # --- ---- -----
```

This works just fine till I tried to change the role of a new user to `supplier`.

```
ValidationError: ['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']
```

The issue is due to that overridden [`get_inlines()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_inlines) method. When I comment out the `get_inlines()` it works fine and this is only happening for the role `supplier`. I tried to tackle this but unabled to come up with a solution.

Hoping for guidance to solve the issue, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of research finally found a [solution](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25559#comment:4), although I cannot exactly explain why it happening (might be related to not having related stock instances and suddenly having relations to stock instances when changed into role supplier).

Anyway, instead of overriding the `get_inlines()` method, overriding [`change_view()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.change_view)and using a conditional approach can solve the problem,

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    inlines = []

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
        self.inlines = []
    
        try:
            obj = self.model.objects.get(pk=object_id)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        else:
            if obj.role == SUPPLIER:
                self.inlines = [SupplierStockInline,]
        return super(UserAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
```